# What does exit code 6 mean in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting exit code 6 when I trying to invoke Post action on Flowdock API.

I am trying to integrate Flowdock with Jenkins. It's working when I run it as post build job. But it's failing with exit code 6 when I am converting it into Jenkinsfile

```
def flowdockURL = "https://api.flowdock.com/v1/messages/team_inbox/${apiToken}"
    def payload = JsonOutput.toJson([source : "Jenkins",
                                     project : env.JOB_BASE_NAME,
                                     from_address: fromAddress,
                                     from_name: 'CI',
                                     subject: subject,
                                     tags: tags,
                                     content: content,
                                     link: env.BUILD_URL
                                     ])
    sh """#!/bin/bash
        echo "Sending Flowdock notification..."
        curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -s -d \'${payload}\' ${flowdockURL}
    """
```

I am expecting it to create a tag in flowdock. But it fails. Error is as follows

ERROR:

```
[Pipeline] sh
Sending Flowdock notification...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 6
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with jenkins, that's the exit code from curl. According to this https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html it means "Couldn't resolve host"

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. The code was not able to resolve the host because it is sitting behind corporate firewall. Exporting proxy just before the operation solved the problem.

Comment: Great! Gonna make my comment to an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit code is from curl, not from Jenkins. According to [this](http://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html) it means "Couldn't resolve host"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Jenkinsfile, but as far as I found in this link:

[Job Exit Status](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Exit+Status)

Code 6: SIGABRT The program called the abort() function. This is an emergency stop.